# How to find if the RecyclerView is being Scrolled up or down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have  a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` , i want to find inside the method `getItemOffsets` of the Class `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` if the user is scrolling up or down . Below is my code inside the class `GridDividerDecoration` where i draw borders between the items.

```
public class GridDividerDecorations extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private int mInsets;
List<Integer> itemsHeaderPos= new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> itemsPos= new ArrayList<>();
List<GadgetItem> mList = new ArrayList<>();
int lastItem;
int itemPosition, itemposition2 = 0;

public GridDividerDecorations(Context context,List<GadgetItem> mList ) {
    this.mList = mList;
    mInsets = 6;
}


@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    itemPosition = ((RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).getViewAdapterPosition();

    if ((parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(itemPosition) == 0))
        itemsHeaderPos.add(itemPosition);
    if((parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(itemPosition) != 0))
        itemsPos.add(itemPosition);

    outRect.top = mInsets;

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = (GridLayoutManager)parent.getLayoutManager();
    if(itemPosition == layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition())
        outRect.right = mInsets;

        if (itemPosition % 2 == 0 && itemsHeaderPos.get(itemsHeaderPos.size() - 1) % 2 == 0) {
            if (parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(itemPosition) != 0)
                outRect.left = mInsets;
        } else if (itemPosition % 2 == 0 && itemsHeaderPos.get(itemsHeaderPos.size() - 1) % 2 != 0) {
            if (parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(itemPosition) != 0) {
                outRect.right = mInsets;
            }
        }

}
}
```

The thing is that when I scroll up the dividers are painted upside down, so finding if the user scroll ups i can revert my implementation. Thank you!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if scrolled up or down with an OnScrollChangeListener:

```
recycler.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        if(oldScrollY - scrollY > 0) {
            // do stuff
        }
        else {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No , you cannot use setOnScrollChangeListener with `recyclerView`

Comment: "setOnScrollChangeListener" requires API 23 and above.